# Assigning values based on varying and mutable criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, dummy-variable, inversion

I am generating a dataframe with dummy variables using the `fastDummies` for later modeling using two character variables.

The original looking something like this:

```
PID Flag1   Flag2   Var_1   Var_2
0001    0   0   AB  AB
0001    0   0   CD  CD
0001    1   0   EF  EF
0001    0   0   GH  GH
0001    0   0   IJ  IJ
0001    0   1   KL  KL
0001    0   0   MN  MN
0001    1   0   OP  OP
0001    0   0   QR  QR
0001    0   1   ST  ST
0001    0   0   UV  UV
0001    1   0   WX  WX
0001    0   0   YZ  YZ
```

And `fastDummies` will generate an output of `Var_1` and `Var_2` like the following:

```
PID Flag1   Flag2   Var_1   Var_2   Var_1_AB    Var_1_CD    Var_1_EF    Var_1_GH    Var_1_IJ    Var_1_KL    Var_1_MN    Var_1_OP    Var_1_QR    Var_1_ST    Var_1_UV    Var_1_WX    Var_1_YZ    Var_2_AB    Var_2_CD    Var_2_EF    Var_2_GH    Var_2_IJ    Var_2_KL    Var_2_MN    Var_2_OP    Var_2_QR    Var_2_ST    Var_2_UV    Var_2_WX    Var_2_YZ
0001    0   0   AB  AB  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0001    0   0   CD  CD  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0001    1   0   EF  EF  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0001    0   0   GH  GH  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0001    0   0   IJ  IJ  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0001    0   1   KL  KL  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0001    0   0   MN  MN  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0001    1   0   OP  OP  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0001    0   0   QR  QR  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0001    0   1   ST  ST  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0001    0   0   UV  UV  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0001    1   0   WX  WX  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0001    0   0   YZ  YZ  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

However, the data contains flags for encoding whether or not a variable needs to be inverted (in this case, flipped from 0 to 1 or vise-verse), indicated with `Flag_1` and `Flag_2`.

Which would need to look something like this:

```
PID Flag1   Flag2   Var_1   Var_2   Var_1_AB    Var_1_CD    Var_1_EF    Var_1_GH    Var_1_IJ    Var_1_KL    Var_1_MN    Var_1_OP    Var_1_QR    Var_1_ST    Var_1_UV    Var_1_WX    Var_1_YZ    Var_2_AB    Var_2_CD    Var_2_EF    Var_2_GH    Var_2_IJ    Var_2_KL    Var_2_MN    Var_2_OP    Var_2_QR    Var_2_ST    Var_2_UV    Var_2_WX    Var_2_YZ
1   0   0   AB  AB  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   CD  CD  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   EF  EF  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   GH  GH  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   IJ  IJ  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   KL  KL  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   MN  MN  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   OP  OP  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   QR  QR  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   ST  ST  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   UV  UV  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   WX  WX  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   YZ  YZ  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Where a 1 on `Flag_1` indicates a flip from 0 to 1 on the dummy variable created using `Var_1` and a 1 on `Flag_2` is indicative of a 0 to 1 flip on the dummy variable created using `Var_2`.

I was originally going to create a function to do this that reads in the dataframe and parses values based on strings and column names and deploy it via `lapply`, but I feel like there's a way to do this using `dplyr/tidyverse` via `mutate_at` or `mutate_all` that can be manipulated with the standard variable names that I'm just missing.

Any suggestions at all on how to accomplish this in a simpler manner would be appreciated.

Some code to generate the aforementioned dataframe:

```
list.of.packages <-
  c("data.table", "tidyverse", "stringr","janitor","fastDummies")
new.packages <-
  list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
if (length(new.packages))
  install.packages(new.packages)

lapply(list.of.packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

df = data.frame(PID = c(0001,0001,0001,0001,0001,0001,0001,0001,0001,0001,0001,0001,0001), Flag1 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0), Flag2 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0), Var_1 = c("AB","CD","EF","GH","IJ","KL","MN","OP","QR","ST","UV","WX","YZ"), Var_2 = c("AB","CD","EF","GH","IJ","KL","MN","OP","QR","ST","UV","WX","YZ"))
df <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "Var_1", remove_selected_columns=FALSE, omit_colname_prefix=FALSE)
df <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "Var_2", remove_selected_columns=FALSE, omit_colname_prefix=FALSE)
```

Comment: FYI, `mutate_at` and `mutate_all` are deprecated, preferring `across` instead.

Comment: Also, whilst it's *possible* to do what you want with your data frame in its current format, you'd find it easier to do if it were tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  It isn't at the moment because information you need (the suffices `1` and `2`) are contained in column names.   Having tidy data will likely make your downstream processing simpler too.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data that doesn't require `fastDummies` to generate.  I suggest `dput(df))`.

Comment: @Limey, while you're right to suggest less ambiguous data provision, in this case it is straight-forward: copy the code block and use `read.table(text=clipr::read_clip(), header=TRUE)` (or replace `clipr::` with `readClipboard()` or whatever your OS supports, I find `clipr` more reliable across platforms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a two-`across` method:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat1new <- dat1 %>%
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("Var_1_"),
      ~ if_else(Var_1 == sub(".*_", "", cur_column()) & Flag1 > 0, +!., .)),
    across(starts_with("Var_2_"),
      ~ if_else(Var_2 == sub(".*_", "", cur_column()) & Flag2 > 0, +!., .))
  )
dat1new
#    PID Flag1 Flag2 Var_1 Var_2 Var_1_AB Var_1_CD Var_1_EF Var_1_GH Var_1_IJ Var_1_KL Var_1_MN Var_1_OP Var_1_QR Var_1_ST Var_1_UV Var_1_WX Var_1_YZ Var_2_AB Var_2_CD Var_2_EF Var_2_GH Var_2_IJ Var_2_KL Var_2_MN Var_2_OP Var_2_QR Var_2_ST Var_2_UV Var_2_WX Var_2_YZ
# 1    1     0     0    AB    AB        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 2    1     0     0    CD    CD        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 3    1     1     0    EF    EF        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 4    1     0     0    GH    GH        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 5    1     0     0    IJ    IJ        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 6    1     0     1    KL    KL        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 7    1     0     0    MN    MN        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 8    1     1     0    OP    OP        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0
# 9    1     0     0    QR    QR        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0
# 10   1     0     1    ST    ST        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 11   1     0     0    UV    UV        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0
# 12   1     1     0    WX    WX        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0
# 13   1     0     0    YZ    YZ        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1
all.equal(dat1new, dat2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Walkthrough:

- `across` is the preferred method over `mutate_at`, it should look similar-enough.
- Using the trailing `_` in `starts_with("Var_1_")` should match only the columns we want and skip the literal `Var_1` column.
- `sub(...)` converts each column name to just the two-letter code found in `Var_1`
- when the two ("this" column and `Var_1`) match and `Flag1` is set, then use `+!.` which is a shortcut way to convert an integer to logical, invert it, then back to integer.
- repeat for `_2_` variables

---

Data: `dat1` is your original (second data code block), `dat2` is your desired output (third data code block).

```r
dat1 <- structure(list(PID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Flag1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Flag2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1 = c("AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "KL", "MN", "OP", "QR", "ST", "UV", "WX", "YZ"), Var_2 = c("AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "KL", "MN", "OP", "QR", "ST", "UV", "WX", "YZ"), Var_1_AB = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_CD = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  0L, 0L), Var_1_EF = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_GH = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_IJ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_KL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_MN = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_OP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_QR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_ST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_UV = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_WX = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Var_1_YZ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Var_2_AB = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_CD = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_EF = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_GH = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_IJ = c(0L,  0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_KL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_MN = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_OP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_QR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_ST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_UV = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_WX = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  1L, 0L), Var_2_YZ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
dat2 <- structure(list(PID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Flag1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Flag2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1 = c("AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "KL", "MN", "OP", "QR", "ST", "UV", "WX", "YZ"), Var_2 = c("AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "KL", "MN", "OP", "QR", "ST", "UV", "WX", "YZ"), Var_1_AB = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_CD = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  0L, 0L), Var_1_EF = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_GH = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_IJ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_KL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_MN = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_OP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_QR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_ST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_UV = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_WX = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_1_YZ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Var_2_AB = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_CD = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_EF = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_GH = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_IJ = c(0L,  0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_KL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_MN = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_OP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_QR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_ST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_UV = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Var_2_WX = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  1L, 0L), Var_2_YZ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: So this is unrelated to the question itself, but what if I wanted to make & Flag1 > 0 multi conditional. Say, wanted to make it so that Flag1 OR Flag2 > 0 causes the transform. Would it just be in parentheses? 

Further, if Var_1_ wasn't exclusive, would introducing a constraint such as where(as.numeric) suffice to restrict it to the non-characters?

Comment: Also could you explain the Var_1/2 == sub(".*_", "", cur_column() part of the code? It works fantastically in the sample but it's failing spectacularly in my real data so I don't think it's reading the columns correctly.

Comment: Actually nevermind. It occurs to me that the variable name is supposed to be what the ._ , cur_column() is being attached to. Apologies.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Since `across` is iterating over multiple columns, `cur_column()` in each iteration returns the specific column name, as in `"Var_1_AB"`. The `sub(..)` converts that to `"AB"` so we can match it against `Var_1`'s value.

Comment: As to using `where(as.numeric)`, you can use that but need to somehow guard against inadvertently iterating over `Flag_*` and `PID`. It might be easier to select a range of columns, as in `across(Var_1_AB:Var_2_YZ, ~ ...)`, or an exclusion of columns, as in `across(-c(PID, Flag0, Flag1, Var_1, Var_2), ~ ...)`.

Comment: Yeah in my case, the strings are coming from columns with much longer strings called `term_names` and `concept_tags` so it's a little more difficult to parse than the example I gave.

Comment: Yeah I found the issue. The `sub` call just needs some more nuanced parsing.
Thanks much!

Comment: Actually if you're feeling generous, could you just provide a brief snippet on how to print what it's passing via sub and current_col() so that I can tell if it's reading this adaptation correctly?

Comment: I think you're in a better position: change it to `across(..., ~ { browser(); if_else(...); })`, and you'll be entered into a debugger session. While in that, you can see things like: `.` (current data), `cur_column()` (current column name), etc. Once you're done with that, you can type `c` to continue on to the next column or `Q` to quit/interrupt immediately out of the debugger (without iterating any further).

Comment: That was extremely helpful. Turns out `cur_column()` was all that was needed based on the way I had set things up in the dummy coding.
Thanks so much!